# Apply function on each cell in a data.frame

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.frame like this:

```
G5_01
   X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
1:                                  0/0                                  0/0
2:                                  0/0                                  1/1
3:                                  0/1                                  0/0
```

I want to calculate variations in each cell and convert it to:

> ```
>   X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
> 1:                                  0                                  0
> 2:                                  0                                  2
> 3:                                  1                                  0
> ```

data.table seemed to be able to deal with this and my script as shown below:

```
library(data.table)

G5_02<-setDT(G5_01)[,lapply(.SD,function(x) sum(as.numeric(strsplit(x,"/")[[1]][1]),
                                                as.numeric(strsplit(x,"/")[[1]][2])))]
```

But it only gives me the result of the first row

> ```
>    X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
> 1:                                    0                                    0
> ```

Any suggestions on how should I fix it?

Comment: I don't know much about `data.table` but can you change the `lapply` to `apply` and set `margin =1` to iterate over each row?

Comment: `mt2$meanvar <- setDT(mt2)[,apply(.SD, 1, mean)]`  - something like this, where mt2 is the `mtcars` dataset

Comment: @Mike thanks, but I need this function to be applied to each cell instead of row or column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try the code below, where `nchar()` and `gsub()` are used

Here are two solutions with base R:

- **Solution 1**: (might be faster than `sapply()`, `apply()` or `lapply()` approaches)

```
G5_02 <- data.frame(nchar(gsub("[^1]","",as.matrix(G5_01))))
```

- **Solution 2**:

```
G5_02 <- data.frame(sapply(G5_01, function(x) nchar(gsub("[^1]","",x))))
```

such that

```
> G5_01
  X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
1                                    0                                    0
2                                    0                                    2
3                                    1                                    0
```

**DATA**

```
G5_01 <- structure(list(X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 = c("0/0", 
"0/0", "0/1"), X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02 = c("0/0", 
"1/1", "0/0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only have to handle 1s and 0s, then a possible solution can be to count the 1s, i.e.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(i)stringr::str_count(i, '1'))][]

#   X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
#1:                                    0                                    0
#2:                                    0                                    2
#3:                                    1                                    0
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't thought that count 1s would be more convenient in this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(G5_01)[, X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 := as.numeric(substr(X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02, 1, 1)) + as.numeric(substr(X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02, 3, 3))][, X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02 := as.numeric(substr(X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02, 1, 1)) + as.numeric(substr(X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02, 3, 3))]

G5_01
         X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
    1:                                    0                                    0
    2:                                    0                                    2
    3:                                    1                                    0
```

**Data**

```
G5_01 <- read.table(text = 'X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
                                  0/0                                  0/0
                                  0/0                                  1/1
                                 0/1                                  0/0', header = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `rowSums` after doing the splitting with `read.table`

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) rowSums(read.table(text = x,
        sep="/", header = FALSE)))
df
#  X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
#1                                    0                                    0
#2                                    0                                    2
#3                                    1                                    0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 = c("0/0", 
"0/0", "0/1"), X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02 = c("0/0", 
"1/1", "0/0")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table::tstrsplit` to get a transposed string-split (like e.g. `purrr::transpose(strsplit(x, '/'))`) we can then convert to numeric and add them together

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_all(~ 
    data.table::tstrsplit(., '/') %>% 
      map(as.numeric) %>% 
      do.call(what = '+'))

#   X8803713069_R01C02_8803713069_R01C02 X8803713069_R02C02_8803713069_R02C02
# 1                                    0                                    0
# 2                                    0                                    2
# 3                                    1                                    0
```